# Determining inner viewport width in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, css, pandoc, reveal.js

Using pandoc to create reveal.js slides.
I am trying to approximate another slide design that has a sidebar image covering 20% of the screen from the left of the window.

And then text split into columns so that part of the text is over the left image, and the rest of the text is over the right side.

I have a solution that works if there is a 50% split, but if I use the same solution for 20%, when the window resizes, then the 20% of the window does not match the 20% of the slide viewport.

What can I use to determine how wide the slides are in reveal.js?  And can I use that value to set the width of the background image?

Example pandoc markdown ( cool_things.png is just a red image )

```
---
title: Cool things slide
---

## {data-background-color=white data-background-image=./cool_things.png data-background-size="50vw" data-background-position="top left" }

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="50%"}
### cool this works
:::
::: {.column width="50%"}

* cool things are cool
* This works correctly.
* every resize has the background image matching the column of text exactly
:::
::::::::::::::

## {data-background-color=white data-background-image=./cool_things.png data-background-size="20vw" data-background-position="top left" }

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="20%"}
### not so cool
:::
::: {.column width="80%"}
* This does not handle resizes too happily
* it _can_ work, depending on the aspect ratio
* otherwise the column will not match the background image
:::
::::::::::::::
```

I am aware of how to set the slide width to be 100% of the window, but I would prefer to not manage the resizes manually and to try and keep it as close to markdown as possible.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not that familiar with reveal.js, but you could just inject some CSS with e.g. [`pandoc --css myfile.css`](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--css)

Comment: Thanks, have done that for other customizations, the complexity with reveal.js is that it maintains a different size for the slides, and adjusts that size reactively